# private/public Field is not seen in inspector when I use GridLayoutGroup in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

private/public Field is not seen in inspector when i using GridLayoutGroup

here is the example

[image]

This is how I am defining my variables:

```
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using UnityEngine.UI; 
using UnityEngine; 
using UnityEditor; 

public class Myscript : GridLayoutGroup 
{ 
    [SerializeField] private bool ishhh; 
}
```

Comment: Add in your question how you are defining the variables inside the script, and mention which variables you consider should be shown in the inspector

Comment: still it is not visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Unity built-in components have an according [`[CustomEditor]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CustomEditor.html) overwriting the default Inspector.

In specific the [`GridLayoutGroup`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.GridLayoutGroup.html) has a custom inspector called [`GridLayoutGroupEditor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.GridLayoutGroupEditor.html) overwriting the inspector for any class derived from [`GridLayoutGroup`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.GridLayoutGroup.html).

→ You have to inherit from it in order to make a custom editor for a class derived from [`GridLayoutGroup`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.GridLayoutGroup.html).

In order to make additional fields visible you could do something like e.g.

```
using UnityEditor;

...

[CustomEditor(typeof(Myscript))]
public class MyScriptEditor : GridLayoutGroupEditor
{
    private SerializedProperty ishhh;

    // Called when the Inspector is loaded
    // Usually when the according GameObject gets selected in the hierarchy
    private void OnEnable ()
    {
        // "Link" the SerializedProperty to a real serialized field
        // (public fields are serialized automatically)
        ishhh = serializedObject.FindProperty("ishhh");
    }

    // Kind of the Inspector's Update method
    public override void OnInpectorGUI ()
    {
        // Draw the default inspector
        // base.OnInspectorGUI();

        // Fetch current values into the serialized properties
        serializedObject.Update();

        // Automatically uses the correct field drawer according to the property type
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(ishhh);

        // Write back changed values to the real component
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

---

**Important:** Place this script in a folder called `Editor` so it is stripped of in a build to avoid built-errors regarding the `UnityEditor` namespace.

Alternatively (since I can see that you already have a `using UnityEditor` in your example code) you can leave it in the same script but then you have to manually use [`#if Pre-Processors`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) in order to strip all code-blocks/-lines off that use something from the `UnityEditor` namespace like

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR

    using UnityEditor;

#endif

...

#if UNITY_EDITOR

    // any code using UnityEditor

#endif
```

Otherwise you won't be able to build your app since the `UnityEditor` only exists in the Unity Editor itself and is completely stripped off for builds.

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone so no warranty but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: i have remove base.OnInspectorGUI(); it giving nullrefrenceException 

now it is visible Thank You so much